# (Ajax+php) Почему после POST запроса посылается пустой GET запрос?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Я пытаюсь забрать значения из двух полей, передать их POST запросом и вывести их на странице без перезагрузки. Но сразу после успешной обработки POST запроса посылается пустой GET запрос, который перезагружает страницу.

Мой код:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>lab2_ajax</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="add_form">
        <input type="text" id="nameField" placeholder="Введите имя" required><br>
        <input type="text" id="descriptionField" placeholder="Введите описание" required><br>
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>

    <div id="db_table"></div>



    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#add_form").submit(function(){
            var name = $("#nameField").val();
            var description = $("#descriptionField").val();
            $("#nameField").val('');
            $("#descriptionField").val('');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/add_item.php",
                data: {name: name, description: description},
                success: function(html){
                    $("#db_table").html(html);
                }
            });
            return fasle;
        })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

add_item.php

```
<?
    echo "Скрипт отработан! Ваше имя: ".$_POST['name']." Описание: ".$_POST['description'];
?>
```

Comment: Думаю, срабатывает сабмит. Нужно выключить через `submit(function(event) ... `, `event.preventDefault();` https://stackoverflow.com/a/51552373/9435985

Comment: `return fasle;` -> `return false;`

Comment: @Igor, спасибо! Я очень невнимательный, 2 часа на это потратил...

Comment: @TotalPusher Спасибо! Ваш ответ тоже был максимально полезен!

Comment: `return false;` - такая ошибка должна упасть в консоль. смотрите консоль, и включите параметр, чтобы она не очищалась после перезагрузку страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я неправильно написал `false`))) (Спасибо @igor)

Так же можно отменить событие следующим образом:
`submit(function(event) ... , event.preventDefault();`

stackoverflow.com/a/51552373/9435985 (Спасибо @TotalPusher)